# 303 редирект на сайте

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

Есть интернет-магазин. Все страницы отдают код ответа 303 и перенаправляют на внутреннюю страницу БД и та в свою очередь отдает код 301 и перенаправляет на другие рандомные страницы.
В чем проблема? В файле .htaccess нет 303 редиректа.
Где он может быть прописан и откуда такая лажа вообще может взяться? 
Как это можно исправить?
Может кто знает чего.
До этого интернет-магазин переносили на поддомен.

Comment: Редирект может быть прописан в любом `php` файле. Смотрите подключаемые модули, может они что делают

Comment: спасибо за ответ.
получается во всех папках модулей искать php файлы и смотреть? там же не редиректами это прописано, я так понимаю. какую конструкцию искать?
есть мнение, что этот косяк вылетает на уровне формирования чпу.

Comment: Возможно у вас в настройках сайта указан другой домен

Comment: интернет-магазин переносили на поддомен до этого
это могло при переносе случиться? если вы знаете, подскажите пожалуйста как это посмотреть.

Comment: Я вам вряд ли помогу, телепатией не обладаю, а гадать, что у вас за код нет желания

Comment: извините за беспокойство. спасибо

Comment: Вы лучше в вопрос допишите подробности, чем извиняться. На чем хоть написан магазин

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите у себя в `.htaccess`, например, такую строку

`Redirect 303 "/path/to/page.htm" http://www.site.com/path/to/new/page.php`

Если подобного нет, исправьте так, как вам надо.

Comment: Если нет, то исправить... То что исправить?

Comment: в файле .htaccess должна быть подобная конструкция, если она есть исправьте ее так чтоб 303 шла на тут страницу которая вам нужна.

Comment: смотрю файлы .htaccess нет там 303 редиректа